# How to change from a wireless connection to an ethernet connection debian

Tags: debian, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry connected to the internet via wifi. But I want to change it, selecting an ethernet connection. How can I do it? I have found some commands on internet but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Isn't there an interface for that? Or are you trying to get inside through ssh?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to turn off wifi and ethernet should then be available if it is plugged in.

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi off
```